# ModelMapper changes generic type on runtime - weird behavior

Tags: java, maven, modelmapper, generics

I am facing a very strange behavior in Java.
I got two different classes that has no hierarchical connection:
Class Template (Type hierarchy is Object -> A ->  B -> Template), and class TemplateDto (Object -> TemplateDto).

I am using ModelMapper (org.modelmapper.ModelMapper) for mapping between the two classes (which uses the default mapping since the field names are identical).

There is the following code:

```
List<Template> templates = cvService.getTemplates();
List<TemplateDto> resultDtos = new ArrayList<TemplateDto>();
modelMapper.map(templates,resultDtos);
TemplateDto example = resultDtos.get(0);
```

And the last line throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vs.framework.domain.cv.Template cannot be cast to com.vs.framework.dto.cv.TemplateDto
```

This is very weird. When i am debugging this section i see that after the mapping, resultDtos is a list of type List instead of List which blows my mind.

I have tried to clean my tomcat, maven clean install but it still happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on their tutorial, you don't appear to be using that function correctly at all. http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

Comment: I am using model mapper for a while, never had problems with this type of mapping (there are many ways to map). Anyway, my question is not about the use of modelmapper but about the weird behavior of Generic type that is being changed on runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java implements generics with *type erasure*, meaning that the runtime code has no way of knowing that your `ArrayList` is supposed to be an `ArrayList<TemplateDto>`.

http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/generics/ describes how to use a `TypeToken` to get around this problem with lists. It should look something like this:

```
List<Template> templates = cvService.getTemplates();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<TemplateDto>>() {}.getType();

List<TemplateDto> resultDtos = modelMapper.map(templates, listType);
TemplateDto example = resultDtos.get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, it looked awkward to me that in debug mode i see an array with a certain generic type that contains some other type's objects, but when i read about type erasure it all makes sense - the arrays are actually type-less on runtime.

Comment: Not sure why this got marked as an answer since you still end up with the wrong type. resultDto's will contain Templates instead of TemplateDtos.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Are you sure? I'll admit I haven't tested this myself, but all the documentation and many other answers (with many upvotes) I'm finding online point to this as the right approach.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yeah, the `TypeToken` approach **IS** how you deal with generics in ModelMapper. However, `List<TemplateDto>` and `List<Template>` are the same exact type at runtime (thanks type erasure!), so ModelMapper will just copy the references over and you end up with the wrong type that was type erased to the right type. You can "work-around" the issue by setting ModelMapper up with deep-copy enabled, but then it's doing deep copy for EVERY "same type". I ran into this issue when my "TemplateDto" response contained all the fields in "Template" when it wasn't supposed to.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Although I did get ModelMapper working with deep copy enabled (and had to make a custom converter for URI since ModelMapper doesn't know how to make one), I ended up ditching ModelMapper for MapStruct. MapStruct does do deep copies (on objects, but not types) as well, but its orders of magnitude faster then ModelMapper. So kill two birds with one stone. I do like ModelMapper's "loosey goosey" automatic mapping mode though :)...

Comment: @SledgeHammer: Did you remember to include the `{}`? "Here we create an **anonymous subclass** of the `TypeToken` class, passing `List<String>` as the type parameter. **This allows the resulting `listType` to contain the captured type information that is otherwise erased at runtime** so that ModelMapper knows we mean to map numbers to a List of Strings." https://modelmapper.org/user-manual/generics/

Comment: In other words, even though `List<TemplateDto>` and `List<Template>` are exactly the same object at runtime, the anonymous subclass created by `new TypeToken<List<TemplateDto>>() {}` still knows that it has an unerased type of `List<TemplateDto>` associated with it. So when the input is a List, and an item in that List is a `Template`, it should know to convert it to a `TemplateDto`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yeah, it wouldn't even build without it. In my case (to be more specific), I have `Page<MyPojo>` to `Page<MyPojoDto>`. I define `Page` and `MyPojo/MyPojoDto`. `Page` contains the `List<T>` collection. When I run it through ModelMapper, ModelMapper does return a `Page<MyPojoDto>` object, but through type erasure, the `List<T>` collection actually holds all `MyPojo`'s instead of `MyPojoDto`'s

Comment: It may work differently if you do it on the list directly, but it sure doesn't work if you do it on an object that contains the list -- UNLESS, as I mentioned, you turn on deep-copy mode.

In the end of the day, its a moot point ... converting 1000 of my `Page<MyPojo>` to `Page<MyPojoDto>` in ModelMapper took about 1500ms vs. 11ms in MapStruct. Yes, MapStruct is that much faster.

And yes, both ModelMapper & MapStruct instances were re-used properly. If you don't trust my benchmarks, Baeldung saw similar results: https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was trying to understand (as you asked) how this sort of answer was so widely accepted when you found that it didn't work. But it probably _does_ work given the use case provided by the OP, and you found a different case where it does not. I absolutely believe you, and have never used either framework myself, and haven't actually touched Java in several years. I just want to make sure my answers get fixed if they are wrong. Thanks for clarifying.