# ModelMapper with generic custom type

Tags: java, generics, modelmapper

I'm using Java library [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org) to map my local (JPA) model to a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) version.

**Model**

```
@Entity
public class City {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String postalCode;
    private String name;

    // getter/setter/etc.
}
```

**DTO**

```
public class CityDto {
    private Long id;
    private String postalCode;
    private String name;

    // getter/setter/etc.
}
```

**Wrapper**

I'm going to pass lists of these classes with an additional int, for which I created a genericly typed wrapper class.

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    private List<T> entities;
    private Integer count;

    //getter/setter/etc.
}
```

**Question**

Now, I want to convert a `Wrapper<City>` into a `Wrapper<CityDto>`. I thought that it's the same as converting a `List<City>` into `List<CityDto>` as explained in the answer to [ModelMapper changes generic type on runtime - weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29105900).

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // prepare
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
    Wrapper<City> wrapper = ...

    // act
    Type type = new TypeToken<Wrapper<CityDto>>() {}.getType();
    Wrapper<CityDto> cityDtos = modelMapper.map(wrapper, type);

    // check
    Assertions.assertTrue(cityDtos.getEntities().get(0) instanceof CityDto);
}
```

This test fails. I get the same exception as in the aforementioned question

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my.model.City cannot be cast to com.my.dto.CityDto

The nested list has objects of the type `City` and not the expected `CityDto`. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Remark**

As a workaround I am doing something like this.

```
Wrapper<City> wrapper = ...
List<CityDto> cityDtos = modelMapper.map(wrapper.getEntities(), new TypeToken<List<CityDto>>() {}.getType());
Wrapper<CityDto> converted = new Wrapper<>(cityDtos, wrapper.getCount());
```

That works, but I'd like to know why my original idea is not working.